# Wild cards in log.check in testfixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am using testfixures `log.check()` to verify the output of my logging.  My log statement contains variable parts like session and duration. For example:

```
2014-02-13T12:04:40.013822 user=user action=do_x session=4a5869aa-f581-4263-a567-918b792587e5 duration=200
```

My `log.check()` looks like this, but isn't currently working.

```
...
log.check(
              ('root', 'INFO', '2014-02-13T12:04:40.013822 user=user action=do_x  session=4a5869aa-f581-4263-a567-918b792587e5 duration=200'),
...
```

Is it possible to check the first part but allow wildcards for the second?

@Edit

@will-hart Apologies, the current problem is my log statement does not match my expectation. My log line consists of static text (keys) and variables (values). Problem is some values are generated in the method, like the session_id. Therefore I cannot write a meaningful expectation as it will never match the generated log statement in the method.

What I'm after is almost a "contains" check, to verify presence of those values I know are static and I can mock.

I actually moved away from testfixtures and trying to achieve this with Mock instead, by mocking my logger and then calling assert_called_with("var1=%s var2=%s var3=s%", var1, var2, var3), but the issue remains, if var1 and var2 are values returned from method calls, I can mock them, but lets say var3 is a timestamp. This gets generated inside the method, So in my test, I don't want to assert the value of val3. In Java you can use any() which will match any value. I can't find anything equivalent in Python.

Comment: Hi there - I may be missing it because I'm not intimately familiar with testfixtures, but your question seems a little unclear - what isn't working, what do you want to happen and which are the "first" and "second" parts?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach was to not use testfixtures but to mock my logger and pass to the Class constructor so I could mock it.

So my log statements look like:

```
self.logger.info("%s user=%s action=%s nodegroup=%s session=%s", datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(), options.username, options.action, options.nodegroup, str(session_id))
```

And in the test I could verify the output such that:

```
action_log_text = '%s user=%s action=%s nodegroup=%s session=%s'
fin_log_text = '%s %s user=%s action=%s nodegroup=%s session=%s duration=%s'

...

calls = [call(self.action_log_text, ANY, options.username, options.action, options.nodegroup, ANY),
                 call(self.fin_log_text, ANY, '[FIN]', options.username, options.action, options.nodegroup, ANY, ANY)]

self.logger.info.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

Turns out python mock has ANY attribute which will match anything. Lovely.